# How to expose new SQL function in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` sql function (I'm targeting Postgres), but after quick inspection of `DSL` class in JOOQ it seems that it is not exposed yet.

How should I approach the problem of adding new function?

- I can try extending `AbstractFunction`, similarly to `org.jooq.impl.Replace`
- Is there any more general way to calling functions not exposed by JOOQ's DSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `REGEXP_REPLACE` function has been supported since jOOQ 3.14](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/string-functions/regexp-replace-function/). In older versions of jOOQ, as always when you're missing out on functionality, use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

```java
public static Field<String> regexpReplace(
    Field<String> in, String pattern, String replacement
) {
    return DSL.field(
        "regexp_replace({0}, {1}, {2})", in.getDataType(), 
        in, 
        DSL.val(pattern), 
        DSL.val(replacement)
    );
}
```